# UTM parameters to my website link but it vanishes when it is open for the first time

Tags: codeigniter-3, query-string, utm

i am adding UTM parameters to my website link but it vanishes when it is open for the first time but if the same link is opened for second time the utm parameters stays
technology i am using is php ci
server apache

i tried enabling query string in my
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; config file but the page loaded is blank